# Use a scope value in a filter

Tags: angularjs

I have a `$scope.gemiddeldeCijfer`. Each object in this scope has two values, a `cijfer` and `aantalDecimalen`. I would like to use the value of `aantalDecimalen` as the number in a number filter.

This is the html, as you can see the number filter now has a set value of `1`. But I would like to replace this value with the value of `cijfer.aantalDecimalen`.

```
  <li ng-repeat="cijfer in gemiddeldeCijfer">
    <b>{{cijfer.cijfer | number:1}}</b> - <b>{{cijfer.aantalDecimalen}}</b>
  </li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kx4Tq/87/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question.

Comment: You're right, forgot to update the fiddle. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want

```
{{cijfer.cijfer | number:cijfer.aantalDecimalen}}
```

Comment: Ah, makes sence. I used `number : {{cijfer.aantalDecimalen}}` which didn't work.